# How to make ABP find db context created by myself?

Tags: blazor, abp

I have used approach of several db contexts in ABP. I seperated ABP Identity module from other ABP modules. First of all I created new context for ABP Identity module using this articles - https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Entity-Framework-Core-Migrations#create-a-second-dbcontext and https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Entity-Framework-Core-Migrations#separating-host-tenant-database-schemas. As a result I have two db contexts.

First one:

```
[ReplaceDbContext(typeof(ITenantManagementDbContext))]
[ConnectionStringName("Default")]
public class OMSBlazorDbContext :
    AbpDbContext<OMSBlazorDbContext>,
    ITenantManagementDbContext
{
    /* Add DbSet properties for your Aggregate Roots / Entities here. */

    public DbSet<CustomerDemographics> CustomerDemographics { get; set; }

    // Tenant Management
    public DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TenantConnectionString> TenantConnectionStrings { get; set; }

    public OMSBlazorDbContext(DbContextOptions<OMSBlazorDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<CustomerDemographics>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("CustomerDemographics");

            b.HasKey(x => x.CustomerTypeId);

            b.HasData(new CustomerDemographics() { CustomerTypeId = 1, CustomerDescription = "Lorem ipsum" });
        });
        builder.ConfigurePermissionManagement();
        builder.ConfigureSettingManagement();
        builder.ConfigureBackgroundJobs();
        builder.ConfigureOpenIddict();
        builder.ConfigureTenantManagement();
    }
}
```

Second one that contains identity:

```
[ReplaceDbContext(typeof(IIdentityDbContext))]
[ConnectionStringName("AbpIdentity")]
public class OMSBlazorIdentityDbContext :
    AbpDbContext<OMSBlazorIdentityDbContext>,
    IIdentityDbContext
{
    public OMSBlazorIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<OMSBlazorIdentityDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<IdentityUser> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<IdentityClaimType> ClaimTypes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<OrganizationUnit> OrganizationUnits { get; set; }

    public DbSet<IdentitySecurityLog> SecurityLogs { get; set; }

    public DbSet<IdentityLinkUser> LinkUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.SetMultiTenancySide(MultiTenancySides.Host);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ConfigureIdentity();
        builder.ConfigureFeatureManagement();
        builder.ConfigureAuditLogging();
    }
}
```

When I start my Blazor app it shows me error that `AbpFeatureGroups` table not found but this table is situated in the second database (that one which can be accessed using `OMSBlazorIdentityDbContext`).

Why ABP cannot find `AbpFeatureGroups` table? Looks like ABP try to find this table in the first db context whileas it is in the second one that's my idea but in that case how to make it use second context. Correct me if I am wrong, please.

Comment: Try adding `[DependsOn(typeof(AbpFeatureManagementEntityFrameworkCoreModule))]` on `OMSBlazorIdentityDbContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soultion that worked was adding to the `appsettings.json`'s `ConnectionString` section connection string with name "AbpFeatureManagement" and setting it to the connection string which lead to database where `AbpFeatureGroups` table is. Hope it helps